# How to access localhost using rdesktop?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, virtualbox-networking, guest-os

installed android x86 in virtualbox on my host Ubuntu 13.10. I'm trying to access the guest from the host through remote desktop but I cant access through either remmina or rdesktop  but i'm getting a "connection closed" error

I enabled remote display in vbox with port 3389 (also tried with 3390)
I tried localhost:3389 and 127.0.0.1 but of no use

please feel free to suggest any method or suggestions on how to enable remote desktop or display as i have never used remote display before.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want tot acces Android by rdp in your Ubuntu? Or from another device?
You can install xrdp in Ubuntu and connect to your Ubuntu using a rdp client and then start virtualbox, Android.
Just connect tot the IP or host adress of your Ubuntu in your rdp cliënt.
http://www.unixmen.com/install-xrdp-in-ubuntu-13-04/
Same for 13.10

Comment: thats cool but i was only able to access ubuntu but not 2 android (i tried both from host and also from  my laptop)